# Angular 2 - binding checkboxes created by ngFor to a boolean array

Tags: angular, checkbox, bind, angular-ngmodel

I am dynamically creating a dropdown list of items using ngFor, looping through a string array (obtained from an SQL query), saved within a service.

```
<li *ngFor="let vehicleClasses of getVehicleClassList(); let i = index" (click)="toggleCheckBox(i)">
  <a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehCB_{{i}}"/>{{vehicleClasses}}
  </a>
</li>
```

The dropdown menu has a checkbox and then the name of the selection (`{{VehicleClasses}}`.
How do I store which checkboxes the user has checked (and preferably from within the service rather than the component)?
Ideally, I want to have a boolean array which store the checkbox value.  If it is possible, can I then bind the checkbox to a value so if, for example, a function were to change all the checkbox booleans, the checkboxes would update?

I've seen `ngModel` used in other similar scenarios - but I have not been able to successfully get it working.

Answer (score 4):

At first, try to avoid using methods in bindings

```
*ngFor="let vehicleClasses of getVehicleClassList();
```

Every time change detection runs such methods are called and change detection runs very often. Assign the result to a property instead and bind to that property.

```
<li *ngFor="let vehicleClass of getVehicleClasses; let i = index" (click)="cbStatus[i] = !cbStatus[i]">
  <a>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cbStatus[i]" />{{vehicleClass}}
  </a>
</li>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  @Input() set vehicleClasses(value) {
    this.vehicles = value;
    this.cbStatus = [];
    for(var p in this.vehicles) {
      this.vehicles.push(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologise for posting an answer so quickly after posting the question.  I could remove the question if preferred - but in case someone else hits a similar problem.

**I didn't realise I could use ngModel to directly bind to a boolean array from within a service.**  Using ngFor's index notation, I could easy bind each checkbox to an element within the boolean array:

```
<li *ngFor="let vehicleClasses of getVehicleClassList(); let i = index" (click)="toggleCheckBox(i)">
  <a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehCB_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="toolbarService.vehicleClassCheckboxes[i]"/>{{vehicleClasses}}
  </a>
</li>
```

The functions I wrote within the service that directly modify the boolean array caused the checkboxes to update correctly.  If anyone else has a better way of doing this, I would love to know - although this happened to fit my scenario well.